# Предпросмотр изображения до загрузки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать предпросмоотр изображения, что бы он выводился в конкретном div до загрузки на сервер? Пробовал такой вариант- не работает

```
<form name="" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="feedback-form-1">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="input-file-row-1">

            <div class="upload-file-container">
                <img id="image" src="#" alt="" />                       
                <div class="upload-file-container-text">
                    <span>Add<br />photo</span>
                    <input type="file" name="pic[]" class="photo" id="imgInput" />
                </div>
            </div>              

        </div>          
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS код

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInput").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: А в чём проблема то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гадаю: у Вас не загружена библиотека jQuery.

Попробуйте - это Ваш код:

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInput").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="feedback-form-1">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="input-file-row-1">

            <div class="upload-file-container">
                <img id="image" src="#" alt="" />                       
                <div class="upload-file-container-text">
                    <span>Add<br />photo</span>
                    <input type="file" name="pic[]" class="photo" id="imgInput" />
                </div>
            </div>              

        </div>          
    </fieldset>
</form>
```